# jQuery Cookies Function not Working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am facing a problem in a jQuery code. It's working in Safari and Firefox but is not working in the Chrome. Here is the explanation of the function below.

Once the user click on closebtn div, and then after refreshing the page, fade and form should not display for 24 hours. But just for that particular user who clicked on "closebtn".

Fade and Form should not work for next 24 hours on that particular ip address or computer or in that browser of that person's computer. Fade and Form can open if the webpage gets opened from any other computer.

Here is the code:

```js
$(function(){

   //var flag = Cookies.get('hideFormAndFade');// this returns value if set else undefined if cookie not found
   var flag=$.cookie("hideFormAndFade")
   alert(flag);
   if(flag == false || flag==undefined){ // if cookie found and if cookie value is not true
    
     setTimeout(function(){
        $('.fade').show();
        $('.closebtn').show();
        $('.form').show();
     },2000);
   }

    $('.closebtn').click(function(){
        $('.fade').hide();
        $('.form').hide();
        var date = new Date();
   var minutes = 30;
   date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
   $.cookie("hideFormAndFade", true , { expires: 1 });
        //Cookies.set('y', "sd"); // 1 is 1 day
        //Cookies.set('hideFormAndFade', true, { path: '/' , expires: 1 }); // 1 is 1 day
    });
});
```

Please help with this functionality.